# How to check if key/value already exist in .json

Tags: python, json

So this is my config.json

```
{
"dictionary": [
    {
        "name": "A",
        "rollno": "B",
        "cgpa": "C",
        "phonenumber": "D"
    },
    {
        "name": "E",
        "rollno": "F",
        "cgpa": "G",
        "phonenumber": "H"
    }
]}
```

and this is my code

```
import os
import json

name = input("Name : ")
rollno = input("No : ")
cgpa = input("cgpa : ")
phonenumber = input("Phone No. : ")
dictionary ={
            "name" : f"{name}",
            "rollno" : f"{rollno}",
            "cgpa" : f"{cgpa}",
            "phonenumber" : f"{phonenumber}"
    }

def write_json(data, filename="Discord\Test Field\config.json"):
    with open(filename,'r+') as file:
        file_data = json.load(file)
        file_data["dictionary"].append(data)
        file.seek(0)
        json.dump(file_data, file, indent = 4)

with open("Discord\Test Field\config.json", 'r') as f:
    json_load = json.load(f)
    name_in_dict = name in json_load
    if name_in_dict == True:
        print("Key already exist")
    else:
        write_json(dictionary)
```

I want to check if name = "A" already exist or not, if already exist it gonna cancel the input, if not exist write_json will run it func

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a list of dictionaries, you can check a condition on each one with [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
config = {
    "dictionary": [
        {
            "name": "A",
            "rollno": "B",
            "cgpa": "C",
            "phonenumber": "D"
        },
        {
            "name": "E",
            "rollno": "F",
            "cgpa": "G",
            "phonenumber": "H"
        }
    ]
}

any(d['name'] == 'A' for d in config['dictionary'] )
# True

any(d['name'] == 'F' for d in config['dictionary'] )
# False
```

`any()` will return `True` at the first item that is `True` from the iterable, and `False` if none match (like `F`).

Comment: so i put it on make the "config = ..." in config.json? and add last 2 command line in the py file?

Comment: I just used `config` for this example since your outer dictionary was not named — I needed to call it something. This is probably the same thing you are calling `json_load`.

Comment: but how if i want to use if statement for it? I mean I want to check if "name" input if already exist or not

Comment: @MorpKnight notice that those two expressions return booleans: True or False. That means you can put `if` in front of them. Or save them to a variable and put `if` in front of that. This means you can do `name_in_dict = any(d['name'] == 'A' for d in config['dictionary'] )`...

Comment: is this like this one? `checkname = any(d['name'] == 'A' for d in config['dictionary'] )`

Comment: aaa thanks @Mark i got it

Answer (score 0):

```py
json = {
"dictionary": [
    {
        "name": "A",
        "rollno": "B",
        "cgpa": "C",
        "phonenumber": "D"
    },
    {
        "name": "E",
        "rollno": "F",
        "cgpa": "G",
        "phonenumber": "H"
    }
]}

newPerson = {
        "name": "E",
        "rollno": "F",
        "cgpa": "G",
        "phonenumber": "H"
    }

def checkIfNameExists(fileData, newEntry):
    for entry in fileData:
        if entry["name"] == newEntry["name"]:
            return False
    return True

print(checkIfNameExists(json["dictionary"], newPerson))
```

i'd loop through each entry and compare each name

Comment: looking over this i can tell i made it in a rush, @mark 's answer might be better suited to you

Comment: Ok, but thanks for helping me

Comment: np, if marks answer worked, be sure to mark the answer as the solution, (the tick on the left, below the vote arrows)